# Java .bin file being written as a standard .txt file

Tags: java, file, binary

I'm trying to write a program that writes a string to a .bin file, but for some reason, the saved file is in the form of a standard .txt file. I wrote a .bin and .txt file for comparison with large string, and they're both the same size. 
It's worth noting that I tried this earlier today and when I wrote to the .bin, it was a jumble of unreadable characters when opened in notepad, and it also had a smaller file size than the text file. How do I achieve this again?

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;

  public class Core
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String outName = "myData.bin";

        byte[] b = "Hello world!".getBytes("UTF-8");
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outName));
        out.write(b);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The file extension has nothing to do with the actual file content. It's only a name. You should also learn more about [Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html). Then you know when to use a DataOutputStream and when not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, text files are simply a specific type of binary file: https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2018/05/difference-between-text-file-and-binary-file.html
When you're writing your file, you're only using text, so everything looks about how you would expect. As soon as I tried running your code and inserting some random bytes, my computer didn't know what program to use to open it, and displayed the weird characters you're expecting

Comment: My apologies, this is just me misunderstanding how this file type works then. Thank you!